Linker can't find CUDA cuSparse functions
I'm writing some CUDA code, and everything works fine, including the line of #include <cusparse.h>, but trying to call any functions from that library results in something like this:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol cusparseCreate referenced in function main"
The Visual Studio CUDA Toolkit includes all necessary Additional Dependencies by default. Given that these dependencies are supposedly linked, why can't my linker find the functions and how do I fix this? Thanks for any help.
